# Best way to convert Date Format in SQL from yyyymmdd to yyyy-mm-dd format

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a bunch of dates in the format yyyymmdd without the "-" separated. What is the easiest way to change to yyyy-mm-dd format using only SQL with read access only. 
i.e 20111230 -> 2011-12-30

One line or optimal performance solution preferable that works in Microsoft SQL

Comment: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: I think it took you longer to post this question than searching Google!

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @dtr VARCHAR(25) = '20111230'

SELECT CONVERT(char(10),CAST(@dtr AS DATE),126)

-- sqlserver 2012
SELECT FORMAT(CAST(@dtr AS DATE),'yyyy-MM-dd' )
```